# Simple (yet wrong) Verilog code

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to implement an ALU by using Verilog language; as a first approach I want to simulate this very simple version of it:

```
module alu(opcode, in1, in2, result);
 input[4:0] opcode;
 input[11:0] in1, in2;
 output[11:0] result;

 case(opcode)
   5'b00000 assign result=in1+in2;
   5'b00010 assign result=in1;
   5'b00011 assign result=in1+1;
   5'b01000 assign result=in1<<1;
   5'b01001 assign result=in1>>>1;
   5'b10001 assign result=in1 && in2;
   5'b10010 assign result=in1 || in2;
 endcase

endmodule
```

Regardless of its simplicity, I'm getting this compilation error:

```
 case(opcode)
           |
 *E,NOTPAR: Illegal operand for constant expression [4(IEEE)].
```

I really can't figure out what's wrong with the code.

Comment: You need to wrap up the case statement in `always@*` block. Moreover, remove the `assign` statements and declare `result` as `reg`. Refer to (this link)[http://referencedesigner.com/tutorials/verilog/verilog_18.php] for case statements understanding in Verilog.

Comment: There's quite a few problems here.  Please review your Verilog reference. Specifically looking at (combinational) always blocks and the syntax for case items.

Comment: So, is it illegal to use wire datatype within case statement?

Comment: It is illegal to drive wires in an always block. You need to change the `result` to `reg`. Or you can remove case statement entirely and make use of nested ternary operator with single assign statement.

Comment: and you should not use `assign` statements inside always blocks as well. meaning no assigns inside your case statement/

Answer (score 6):

1) Put `case` in the combo always block (i.e. `always @ (*)` if you are using verilog 2001 syntax).

2) Drop the `assign` keyword, declare `result` as `output reg`

3) Put `:` after the condition, like `5'b0000:`

4) Take care of the possible overflow in arithmetic operations

5) Logical `and` and `or` will give you a 1-bit result, yet you assign it to the 12-bit output. Maybe you wanted a bitwise version of the aforementioned operations (google the difference)?